# gxt/ExtGwt. Column rendering

Tags: gwt, gxt

What is the best (optimized) way to set an image as a renderer to only one column? (It's always the same image, the image doesn't change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple control like Text (which renders a `div`) and set a custom style name(`CSS` `class`).
Through the `CSS` you can reference the image as background image. This way the client browser will cache the image.

Comment: thanks, and in the end i create new cellRenderer, which returns background image. Then applied this renderer to column.

Comment: you'll implement a class which _implements_ GridCellRenderer, in the `render` method you'll make new `Text` object and set the style by calling `addStyleName`. After that in your CSS file you'll declare the CSS class with the `background-image` property. At the end you will assign this renderer to a certain column, that was my idea.

Comment: It is necessary, you create it,set style and you return this object as result.

Comment: GridCellRenderers do not need to return a Widget - and returning a widget makes the whole grid more expensive to draw, so I would discourage it. Instead, build the html you want as a string, and return that, such as `return "<div class=\"my-background-image\" />";` or `return "<img src=\"path/to/my/image.png\"";`